# xpages dojo text area binding to a dialog list field

Tags: xpages, lotus-formula

I have a `Dojo Text Area` control binding to a field from a form, the field is a Dialog list which uses a simple `@DBColumn` formula:

```
 _view := "vwAuthor";

@Unique ( @DbColumn( "" : "NoCache" ; @DbName ; _view ; 1 ) )
```

I have saved one doc. with the Dojo text area control = Name1, but when I create another new doc. is there any chance to have that `"auto-refresh"` from Clasic Lotus Notes so that When I just type `N` the `Name1` should be displayed?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Create instead of the value picker for your Dojo Text Area a **dialog box** with an input text field with type ahead.

Feed the type ahead with the first column of your view "vwAuthor":

```xml
  <xp:inputText
     ...>
     <xp:typeAhead
        mode="full"
        minChars="1">
        <xp:this.valueList><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                @Unique(@DbColumn("", "vwAuthor", 1))
        }]]></xp:this.valueList>
     </xp:typeAhead>
  </xp:inputText>
```

Comment: Sorry but I think I don't understand: should I replace the dojo textarea with a dialog box control?

Comment: No, you still use the Dojo Text Area but instead of the value picker you have for choosing values next to Dojo Text Area you have a button for calling a dialog box with this type ahead functionality

Answer (score 0):

A text area by default does not offer any data entry assistance. Switch to a regular input box and use the type-ahead support build into XPages. Check the [basic workshop](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/tutorial-intro-to-xpages.htm), especially [Exercise 7](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Tutorial-Introduction-to-XPages-Exercise-7).

Comment: The reason I used Dojo TextArea was that I can any time hit 'enter' and my text would appear in multiple lines.

Comment: I understand, but you need to take a different approach if you want to have typeahead